# Where do you get industry specific stock photos?

Tags: website-design, stock-images

Any other designers have suggestions on how/where to find photography on luxury fashion designers?  I'm looking for legitimate licensing.

I know the main sites like Shutterstock, iStock, and Getty Images. Where do you go about finding more industry specific photographs though? A lot of the stock sites by nature focus on broad topics and subjects for mass appeal. Should I just try to find a professional fashion photographer that might be able to license me out some of his unpublished pieces - where would I even begin finding that?

Comment: Are you sure you need stock images? I'm not sure what the complete concept is but it sounds like a great opportunity for young fashion designers to have their designs featured. Maybe you can collaborate with a designer.

Answer (score 1):

I come across this problem from time to time when designing websites.
I need a specific image and the stock site just don't have what I need.

What I usually do is search Flickr and find an image that would be suitable to use, then simply message the photographer if I could use the image.

Most of the time they let me use it for free and send me the original file if I ask.

In your case you could probably find a professional fashion photographer on Flickr and work out some kind of legitimate licensing deal with them.

Anyways that's my two cent. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

On Dreamstime, if you dont find the image you need, you can ask someone to design/photograph them in the forums and they will be the same price as a regular royalty free image, [check here](http://www.dreamstime.com/forum_2#res4185687).

There will be plenty photographers willing to help and do the shooting you need.

Comment: Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use www.everypixel.com It is a powerful site where you can search through over 40 stock sites at one time.

Full disclosure: I work for the company

Comment: Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details.